# HTML 5 Favicon - Support?

Tags: html, browser, favicon

I was reading the Favicon page on Wikipedia. They mention the HTML 5 spec for Favicon:

> The current HTML5 specification recommends specifying size icons in multiple sizes using the attributes rel="icon" sizes="space-separated list of icon dimensions" within a  tag. [[source](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/links.html#rel-icon)] Multiple icon formats, including container formats such as Microsoft .ico and Macintosh .icns files, as well as Scalable Vector Graphics may be provided by including the icon's content type in the form of type="file content-type" within the  tag.

Looking at the cited article (W3) they show this example:

```
<link rel=icon href=favicon.png sizes="16x16" type="image/png">
<link rel=icon href=windows.ico sizes="32x32 48x48" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon">
<link rel=icon href=mac.icns sizes="128x128 512x512 8192x8192 32768x32768">
<link rel=icon href=iphone.png sizes="57x57" type="image/png">
<link rel=icon href=gnome.svg sizes="any" type="image/svg+xml">
```

My question is do any browsers support the HTML 5 method?

Note: I know Apple uses their `apple-touch-icon` meta tag method over the HTML5 method.

The wikipedia article claims:

> The Google Chrome web browser however, will select the closest matching size from those provided in the HTML headers to create 128×128 pixel application icons when the user chooses the Create application shortcuts... from the "Tools" menu.

How does Internet Explorer (v9 to v11) and Firefox handle this? And is the article correct in how Chrome handles the HTML Favicons? (There is no source cited for Chrome confirming this.)

In searching I wasn't able to really find any (credible) info on HTML 5 Favicon other than the Wikipedia Article.

Comment: Something seems weird in the code above - does html5 allow not quoting attribute values? Answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495310/do-you-quote-html5-attributes

Answer (score 343, accepted):

The answers provided (at the time of this post) are link only answers so I thought I would summarize the links into an answer and what I will be using.

When working to create Cross Browser Favicons (including touch icons) there are several things to consider.

The first (of course) is Internet Explorer. IE does not support PNG favicons until version 11. So our first line is a conditional comment for favicons in IE 9 and below:

```
<!--[if IE]><link rel="shortcut icon" href="path/to/favicon.ico"><![endif]-->
```

To cover the uses of the icon create it at 32x32 pixels. Notice the `rel="shortcut icon"` for IE to recognize the icon it needs the word `shortcut` which is not standard. Also we wrap the `.ico` favicon in a IE conditional comment because Chrome and Safari will use the `.ico` file if it is present, despite other options available, not what we would like.

The above covers IE up to IE 9. IE 11 accepts PNG favicons, however, IE 10 does not. Also IE 10 does not read conditional comments thus IE 10 won't show a favicon. With IE 11 and Edge available I don't see IE 10 in widespread use, so I ignore this browser.

For the rest of the browsers we are going to use the standard way to cite a favicon:

```
<link rel="icon" href="path/to/favicon.png">
```

This icon should be 196x196 pixels in size to cover all devices that may use this icon.

To cover touch icons on mobile devices we are going to use Apple's proprietary way to cite a touch icon:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png">
```

Using `rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed"` will not apply the reflective shine when bookmarked on iOS. To have iOS apply the shine use `rel="apple-touch-icon"`. This icon should be sized to 180x180 pixels as that is the current size recommend by Apple for the latest iPhones and iPads. I have read Blackberry will also use `rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed"`.

As a note: Chrome for Android states:

> The apple-touch-* are deprecated, and will be supported only for a short time. (Written as of beta for m31 of Chrome).

**Custom Tiles for IE 11+ on Windows 8.1+**

IE 11+ on Windows 8.1+ does offer a way to create pinned tiles for your site.

Microsoft recommends creating a few tiles at the following size:

> Small: 128 x 128

> Medium:    270 x 270

> Wide: 558 x 270

> Large: 558 x 558

These should be transparent images as we will define a color background next.

Once these images are created you should create an xml file called `browserconfig.xml` with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<browserconfig>
  <msapplication>
    <tile>
      <square70x70logo src="images/smalltile.png"/>
      <square150x150logo src="images/mediumtile.png"/>
      <wide310x150logo src="images/widetile.png"/>
      <square310x310logo src="images/largetile.png"/>
      <TileColor>#009900</TileColor>
    </tile>
  </msapplication>
</browserconfig>
```

Save this xml file in the root of your site. When a site is pinned IE will look for this file. If you want to name the xml file something different or have it in a different location add this meta tag to the `head`:

```
<meta name="msapplication-config" content="path-to-browserconfig/custom-name.xml" />
```

For additional information on IE 11+ custom tiles and using the XML file [visit Microsoft's website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/dn455106(v=vs.85)).

**Putting it all together:**

To put it all together the above code would look like this:

```
<!-- For IE 9 and below. ICO should be 32x32 pixels in size -->
<!--[if IE]><link rel="shortcut icon" href="path/to/favicon.ico"><![endif]-->

<!-- Touch Icons - iOS and Android 2.1+ 180x180 pixels in size. --> 
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png">

<!-- Firefox, Chrome, Safari, IE 11+ and Opera. 196x196 pixels in size. -->
<link rel="icon" href="path/to/favicon.png">
```

**Windows Phone Live Tiles**

If a user is using a Windows Phone they can pin a website to the start screen of their phone. Unfortunately, when they do this it displays a screenshot of your phone, not a favicon (not even the MS specific code referenced above). To make a "Live Tile" for Windows Phone Users for your website one must use the following code:

[Here are detailed instructions from Microsoft](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2012/10/19/creating-a-custom-tile-to-link-to-your-website/) but here is a synopsis:

*Step 1*

Create a square image for your website, to support hi-res screens create it at 768x768 pixels in size.

*Step 2*

Add a hidden overlay of this image. Here is example code from Microsoft:

```
<div id="TileOverlay" onclick="ToggleTileOverlay()" style='background-color: Highlight; height: 100%; width: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0px; position: fixed; color: black; visibility: hidden'>
  <img src="customtile.png" width="320" height="320" />
  <div style='margin-top: 40px'>
     Add text/graphic asking user to pin to start using the menu...
  </div>
</div>
```

*Step 3*

You then can add thew following line to add a pin to start link:

```
<a href="javascript:ToggleTileOverlay()">Pin this site to your start screen</a>
```

Microsoft recommends that you detect windows phone and only show that link to those users since it won't work for other users.

*Step 4*

Next you add some JS to toggle the overlay visibility

```
<script>
function ToggleTileOverlay() {
 var newVisibility =     (document.getElementById('TileOverlay').style.visibility == 'visible') ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
 document.getElementById('TileOverlay').style.visibility =    newVisibility;
}
</script>
```

**Note on Sizes**

I am using one size as every browser will scale down the image as necessary. I could add more HTML to specify multiple sizes if desired for those with a lower bandwidth but I am already compressing the PNG files heavily using [TinyPNG](https://tinypng.com/) and I find this unnecessary for my purposes. Also, according to [philippe_b](https://stackoverflow.com/users/499917/philippe-b)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23849377/html-5-favicon-support/23852908#23852908) Chrome and Firefox have bugs that cause the browser to load all sizes of icons. Using one large icon may be better than multiple smaller ones because of this.

***Further Reading***

For those who would like more details see the links below:

- [Wikipedia Article on Favicons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon)
- [The Icon Handbook](https://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/chart/)
- [Understand the Favicon](https://web.archive.org/web/20190503161321if_/http://www.jonathantneal.com/blog/understand-the-favicon/) by Jonathan T. Neal
- [rel="shortcut icon" considered harmful](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/rel-shortcut-icon) by Mathias Bynens
- [Everything you always wanted to know about touch icons](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/touch-icons) by Mathias Bynens

Comment: Which size icon (for my bookmark web application) I need for Apple ? ***320x460, 640x920, 640x1096, 72x72, 114x114, 144x144, 768x1004, 1024x748*** ? And for Android ?

Comment: @Kiquenet For the web I use 180x180 for Apple and 196x196 for Android (and other devices as well, except IE 10 and below.)

Comment: [Here are detailed instructions from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html)

Comment: Of all the how do I add a fav icon questions and answers, this one has to be my favorite because it is extremely informative and most of all -- IT WORKS! Thanks man! Using the .PNG format really saved me!

Comment: Custom tiles have either been deprecated or menus have been hidden on the latest version of Edge.

Answer (score 17):

No, not all browsers support the `sizes` attribute:

- Safari: Yes, [it picks the picture that fits best](http://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_compatibility).
- Opera: Yes, [it picks the picture that fits best](http://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_compatibility).
- IE11: Not sure. [It apparently takes the larger picture it finds](http://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_compatibility), which is a bit crude but okay.
- Chrome: No, see bugs [112941](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=112941) and [324820](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=324820). In fact, Chrome tends to load *all* declared icons, not only the best/first/last one.
- Firefox: No, see [bug 751712](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=751712). Like Chrome, Firefox tends to load *all* declared icon.

Note that some platforms define specific sizes:

- [Android Chrome expects a 192x192 icon](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/installtohomescreen), but it favors the icons declared in `manifest.json` if it is present. Plus, [Chrome uses the Apple Touch icon for bookmarks](http://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_compatibility).
- [Coast by Opera expects a 228x228 icon](https://dev.opera.com/articles/opera-coast/#multiple-icon-references).
- [Google TV expects a 96x96 icon](https://developers.google.com/tv/web/docs/design_for_tv#favicons).

Comment: `...yet it favors the Apple Touch icon if it finds it.` Not sure this is completely true anymore, at least not in the future. From the Chrome website: `The apple-touch-* are deprecated, and will be supported only for a short time. (Written as of beta for m31 of Chrome).`

Comment: Yep, but right now Android Chrome 35 picks the 152x152 Apple touch icon and ignores the 196x196 PNG icon (I used a compatibility test: http://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_compatibility_test). I don't know when Google will switch, but my guess is that it won't happen any soon. Well, that's just a guess.

Comment: According _https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27_ the sizes for Apple (**Web clip icon** ) are ***76x76, 120x120, 152x152, 167x167, 180x180***

Comment: According _https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/installtohomescreen_ the sizes for Android are ***36x36, 48x48, 72x72, 96x96, 144x144, 192x192***, maybe too ***128x128***