# How to make a browser icon using PHP?

Tags: php, favicon, ico

I'm aware that doing so in HTML is as simple as this:

```
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
```

However, I have a PHP site, in which:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

to direct the user directly to the main page.

I can't seem to find a way to get a browser tab icon.
What have I tried?

I tried to echo HTML inside index.php with the code, which didn't work. I also tried placing the line of code in some other working header HTML from within index.php. Google has nothing... literally.

The image is a .ico, called 'favicon.ico', is in root, and is recognized as a valid ico file.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

By default, you actually don't need anything in your HTML for a favicon. Simply having a valid favicon.ico in your root should be enough.

Sometimes, when changing favicon you need to clear your browser cache for that site. Also, try accessing the favicon.ico directly: http://example.com/favicon.ico and make sure you can load it.

Here's a good resource about favicons:  [HTML 5 Favicon - Support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23849377/html-5-favicon-support#answer-23851464)

Comment: Again, I'm aware of that. I'm running pure PHP. In my root folder, I have index.php, themes, .htaccess, favicon.ico. No HTML!

Comment: @AricLeather AFAIK that shouldn't matter. I'm assuming you're using Apache to serve your php file(s)? Are you able to open the `favicon.ico` from your browser directly as indicated in my answer?

Comment: Yes, I can open favicon.ico from my browser.