# Minimum Viable Favicon Code

Tags: html, favicon

I'm confused about what's the simplest way to get favicons working on the majority of handsets and browsers.

1) [Some sites](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/touch-icons) suggest that it is enough to use:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="apple-touch-icon-180x180.png">
```

That will work for iOS 8, and should be picked up by Android, BlackBerry, Windows, etc.

2) [Other sites](http://realfavicongenerator.net) insist that every single possible favicon *must* be explicitly specified:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-192x192.png" sizes="192x192">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-160x160.png" sizes="160x160">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-96x96.png" sizes="96x96">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#000000">
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/mstile-144x144.png">
```

3) [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23849377/html-5-favicon-support) says that you just need:

```
<!-- For IE 9 and below. ICO should be 32x32 pixels in size -->
<!--[if IE]><link rel="shortcut icon" href="path/to/favicon.ico"><![endif]-->

<!-- Touch Icons - iOS and Android 2.1+ 180x180 pixels in size. --> 
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png">

<!-- Firefox, Chrome, Safari, IE 11+ and Opera. 196x196 pixels in size. -->
<link rel="icon" href="path/to/favicon.png">
```

Which of the above is going to cover the most browsers / handsets with the minimum amount of effort?

Comment: Check Wikipedia for more info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon

Comment: I'm the author of RealFaviconGenerator, the "solution 2" in your question. RFG doesn't pretend you *must* use all these icons and HTML code. Its rational is: if you want to support as many platforms as possible and given that everything is generated automatically for you (the purpose of RFG after all), well, you can just copy/paste all this in your site. Come on, it's already full of JavaScript and CSS! :) Yet you're not the first to frown at that many lines. Someday RFG will offer a lighter package.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The code in solution 3 is correct but outdated. [Precomposed Touch icons were deprecated in iOS 7](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html) and [Android Chrome does not support 196x196 icons anymore, but 192x192](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/installtohomescreen) ([it really won't use anything above 192x192](http://realfavicongenerator.net/blog/android-chrome-and-its-favicon/); full disclosure: I'm the author of this article).

So:

```
<!-- For IE 9 and below. ICO should be 32x32 pixels in size -->
<!--[if IE]><link rel="shortcut icon" href="/path/to/favicon.ico"><![endif]-->

<!-- Touch Icons - iOS and Android 2.1+ 180x180 pixels in size. --> 
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/path/to/apple-touch-icon.png">

<!-- Firefox, Chrome, Safari, IE 11+ and Opera. 192x192 pixels in size. -->
<link rel="icon" href="/path/to/favicon.png">
```

If you can place `favicon.ico` in the root of the web site, you can even skip its declaration, since IE looks for `/favicon.ico` by convention.

Comment: Ditto on the thank you for RFG. A fantastic tool. I agree though, it would be even better if there were options to generate lighter packages. I'm not a fan of littering the root directory with 30 files just to offer fringe support for what is, after all, an entirely non-essential aspect of the site.

Comment: @Kal Thanks! I admit I'm not fond of cluttering my root directory either. Choosing to put files in a subdirectory is a good compromised.