# how to add site icon which work on all browser?

Tags: html, css, favicon

```
<head>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/anime_logo/favicon32x32.png" size="32x32">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/anime_logo/favicon32x32.png" size="32x32">
</head>
```

my site icon is work only in firefox. how will i change this in order to work to all browser. Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a browser tab icon (favicon) for a website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888377/how-to-add-a-browser-tab-icon-favicon-for-a-website)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need several icons to support all browsers:

- Classic, desktop browsers, which display a small icon in tabs.
- Mobile browsers, which use high definition icons for bookmarks and "add to home screen" use case.
- Modern Windows IE and Edge, which use specific icons for the Metro UI.
- macOS Safari uses a specific, monochromatic icon for pinned tabs and Touch Bar for most recent MacBooks.

There are basically to ways to address all these use cases:

- Tool assisted: you can use [RealFaviconGeneator](https://realfavicongenerator.net/), which generate all the icons and HTML code you need. Full disclosure: I'm the author of this site.
- Manually: The [Favicon Cheat Sheet](https://github.com/audreyr/favicon-cheat-sheet) is an excellent resource.

Comment: i found too many sizes for icon but what's the common size that everyone use.

Comment: This question will give you some insights: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27612244/minimum-viable-favicon-code/27627807 However, in my opinion, you can use the code generated by RealFaviconGenerator (and this is great, because I wrote it :) ). It is light, yet it supports all platforms and use cases.

Comment: ahh I've check your site.. I think it will help me in converting icon.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following link along with your existing one:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/anime_logo/favicon32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
```

so now your markup becomes like this:

**Note** - I've replaced the `size` with the **[sizes](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_sizes.asp)** attribute.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/anime_logo/favicon32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/anime_logo/favicon32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
```

Comment: is it possible to add two types of code in one html body

Comment: these links should be within the head tag, and yes you can have multiple links inside the head tag.

Comment: what if i don't add size

Comment: @H101 Simply follow dupe link in above main comment and you have all your answers