# How can I make an icon for my website?

Tags: html, css, icons, favicon

I'm currently building my website, I want to have a icon that shows up in the browser tab and the bookmark area, and on mobile device on the home screen, if my users want.  I've seen some things about favicons and .ico's, but I've seen websites with icons that are certainly more then 16px by 16px, how do I make a icon for my site that is bigger than 16px by 16px, and implement it?  See screen shot below, i.e. Proton Mail's icon is not 16px by 16px.

Thanks for your time!

---

[image: picture of bookmarks]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888377/how-to-add-a-browser-tab-icon-for-a-website?rq=1

Comment: @SatejS Thanks for the link, solved my question!  Maybe post it as an answer?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23849377/html-5-favicon-support

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 2):

**First**

Find a way to download a logo maker, I would recommend Sothink Logo Maker. 
i.e. `http://www.sothink.com/product/logo-maker/` [sothink logo maker](http://www.sothink.com/product/logo-maker/). for me i would recommend sothink because i have used it and it is great to make icons.

**Secondly**

Save your icon and create multiple icon versions even favicons of all recommended sizes using favicon generator websites. i would recommend for you `http://www.favicon-generator.org/` [favicon generator](http://www.favicon-generator.org/)

**Thirdly**

You may add them to your website. You can add icons or even favicons. here is a simple guide/code of an already answered question on how to add favicons  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888377/how-to-add-a-browser-tab-icon-for-a-website?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks for your effort!  I figured it out!