# Favicon not working in chrome 50

Tags: google-chrome, favicon

Favicon is not working in my latest Chrome update. It was working previously on Chrome 47 but I have updated my Chrome to Version 50 and it stop showing favicon.

Code

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico">
```

Working fine in all other major browsers, any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe try clearing the cache? I see favicons working in all the sites I visit in Chrome v50. What is your code for your favicon on your site?

Comment: Here is my code: <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico">

Answer (score 0):

Your favicon code may be causing the issue. Try the following Favicon code:

```
<!-- For IE 9 and below. ICO should be 32x32 pixels in size -->
<!--[if IE]><link rel="shortcut icon" href="path/to/favicon.ico"><![endif]-->

<!-- Touch Icons - iOS and Android 2.1+ 180x180 pixels in size. --> 
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png">

<!-- Firefox, Chrome, Safari, IE 11+ and Opera. 196x196 pixels in size. -->
<link rel="icon" href="path/to/favicon.png">
```

I've added some comments into the code to cover the sizes used and what browsers they cover.

I've posted an [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23851464/825757) that goes more in-depth into why I chose these sizes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well.. Turns out placing the favicon.ico image in my img folder cleared up the problem. ie your path for the favicon.ico should be "img/favicon.ico"