# does multiple fav icon delay page loading?

Tags: delay, html, favicon

in my web page , I am using more than 10 fav icons , as you can see bellow :

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" href="">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="">
<link rel="manifest" href="">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
```

Should this cause a web page delay ?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML 5 Favicon - Support?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23849377/html-5-favicon-support)

Comment: Particularly, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23852908/6650102), which describes how each browser handles it. *Most* browsers just select the relevant size to load, although the loading time is probably not huge anyway.